# Wifi auto disconnecting and trackpad not working

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, touchpad, wicd

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop (Asus-X542UQ) as dual boot. Initially, it worked fine but a couple of days before it started behaving strangely i.e. wifi started auto disconnecting and touchpad stopped working (both at the same time). After a few minutes when touchpad starts working, it stops working as soon as I click on wifi and wifi also doesn't show network. Everything works fine on reboot but only for 10 minutes.

Things I tried:

1. installed Synaptics driver but nothing happened (synclient touchpadOff=0 doesn't work when trackpad goes off)
2. updated from 18.04 to 18.10 (nothing changed, still same issue)
3. used wicd instead of network manager (wifi still disconnects).

While using a wired connection (Sometimes trackpad goes off). Even Spotify and youtube starts misbehaving when trackpad goes off. External mouse works fine.

Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565

It has become impossible to use my laptop.

Comment: Check if touchpad settings in your system might be causing it to get disabled after connecting an input device, like mouse or a keyboard or after you have typed something on the keyboard. And if it is not really related to network connectivity.

Comment: You seem to be having two separate issues, one with your touchpad and one with your Wi-Fi. Please [edit] your question to make it specific for one issue and add a second question for the other. Also, add at least the output of `lspci` in each of your questions so we know your hardware.